# change event using name attribute of checkbox JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this multiple checkboxes with same name attribute : `myTask`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="1B">
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="2B">
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="3B">
```

and

I have this `jQuery` code to perform every time the user clicks on the checkboxes

```
$("input[name='myTask'").change(function(){
   alert(1);
});
```

is there anything wrong with my script?

Comment: `$("input[name=myTask]").change(function(){` I tried this but still not working..

Comment: Ok after `$("input[name=myTask]")` you may need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){  // your code here })` .. ِAlso keep eyes on console for errors

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name=myTask]").change(function(){
            alert(1);
        });
    });`

Tried this one still not working and I also checked the console log no error found

Comment: You can try  `$(document).on('change' , "input[name=myTask]" , function(){alert(1)})`

Comment: Please hit `f12` and note any console errors. If you wrap it in a `document.load` you shouldn't get any issues (unless it wants you to put your script below your body - which happens. Please check the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check may be something wrong in your code. You have forgot to add one square bracket

```js
$("input[name='myTask']").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="1B">
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="2B">
<input type="checkbox" class="sol-checkbox" name="myTask" value="3B">
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot add one closing square bracket .

Please try below code.

> Way to trigger the on change through the input type.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $("input[name='myTask']").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

> Way to trigger the on change through the class name of the input field.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(".sol-checkbox").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```